# AndroidThings OTA Updates

Tags: android, android-things, android-things-console

On my Raspberry Pi i have installed Developer Preview 5.1 and one application that works as default.

Now is Developer Preview 6 coming. For now to make OTA Updates i recieved a warning, that i should update the OS version.

I have created empty bundle with developer preview 6 and in OTA Updates i have started new Update with it.
After some days my Raspberry has still preview-5.1

I have created apk for my app, zipped it, uploaded with last preview version (only last version can be selected in console) and have started new update with it.
Update has never received the Raspberry.

Raspberry SD Card has 8 GB, Image is 4 GB big.

On https://developer.android.com/things/console/index.html is said, that system image updates with console OTA Updates are possible. Is it so? What have i maked wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I go to my Android Things console I get: `To prepare your devices for OTA updates, you must flash them with Android Things DP6 or higher versions` which to me means that I must flash my hardware with DP6+ before it can get OTA updates.

The release notes for DP6:
https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#preview-6

even refer to the Device Update API: https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/apis/update.html

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean, that AndroidThings could not be used in production for many devices?

Comment: AndroidThings is in developer preview which means NOT production. The whole point is to try things in a prototype or test environment to see if it fits your needs with the understanding that you may need to re-flash the units. I expect that once this goes to production Google wants customers to be able to deploy to many devices.

Comment: As an addendum, DP6 changed the boot partitions of the system image, making it not possible to do a simple OTA. In the future, OTAs should work as expected as the platform becomes more stable.